# "Can not buid tree with empty xml" getting error using html2ps in cakephp 2.3.8

Tags: cakephp, html2pdf

I got this error when tried to download a PDF. It seems the code expect xml string to echo something to the screen before the PDF created.

[image]

Did I miss something in my setup? I have followed the steps explained by this website http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Casmo/2010/06/26/creating-pdf-files-with-html2ps-html2pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Pankaj,

### Cakephp2.3.x the folder name get changed "vendor" to "Vendor". that is why you are getting the error..

Cakephp 1.3.X : In PdfComponent we are using

// Include the class file and create Html2ps instance

```
  App::import('vendor', 'Html2PsConfig', array('file' => 'html2ps'.DS.'config.inc.php')); 
  App::import('vendor', 'Html2Ps', array('file' => 'html2ps'.DS.'pipeline.factory.class.php'));
  parse_config_file(APP .'vendors'. DS .'html2ps'. DS .'html2ps.config');
```

---

Cakephp 2.3.X : In PdfComponent you have to change the code same as bellow..

// Include the class file and create Html2ps instance

```
  App::import('Vendor', 'Html2PsConfig', array('file' => 'html2ps'.DS.'config.inc.php')); 
  App::import('Vendor', 'Html2Ps', array('file' => 'html2ps'.DS.'pipeline.factory.class.php'));
  parse_config_file(APP .'Vendor'. DS .'html2ps'. DS .'html2ps.config');
```

Try this may helpful for you.. :-)